# Illegal Instruction when compiling with -mfma

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen

I am compiling with GCC 5.3.0 on Intel SandyBridge E5-2670.  When I use these flags `-O3 -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -march=native -ffast-math` the code runs without error.  When I add `-mfma` I get illegal instruction.

I figured that using `-march=native` would never produce illegal instructions.  I ran the program with `gdb` and `bt` but it shows a valid (at least to me) stack so I don't think `-mfma` exposed a bad pointer or other memory problem.

```
#0  0x000000000043a59c in ConvexHull::SortConvexHull() ()
#1  0x000000000043badd in ConvexHull::ConvexHull(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>) ()
#2  0x000000000040b794 in Group::BuildCatElement() ()
#3  0x0000000000416b60 in SurfaceModel::ProcessGroups() ()
#4  0x00000000004435c6 in MainLoop(Inputs&, std::ostream&) ()
#5  0x000000000040494e in main ()
```

Then I recompiled with debugging (`-O0 -g`), all other options the same and `gdb` comes back with

```
0x00000000004140df in Eigen::internal::pmadd<double __vector(4)>(double __vector(4) const&, double __vector(4) const&, double __vector(4) const&) (a=..., b=..., c=...)
     at ./../eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/Eigen/src/Core/arch/AVX/PacketMath.h:178
178       __asm__("vfmadd231pd %[a], %[b], %[c]" : [c] "+x" (res) : [a] "x" (a), [b] "x" (b));
```

The backtrace shows that the error starts at line 259

```
using namespace Eigen;
252 gridPnts.rowwise() -= gridPnts.colwise().mean(); //gridPnts is MatrixXd (X by 3)
253 Matrix3d S = gridPnts.transpose() * gridPnts;
254 S /= static_cast<double>(gridPnts.rows() - 1);
255 Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> es(S);
256 Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 2> trans;
257 trans = es.eigenvectors().block<3, 2>(0, 1);
258 MatrixXd output(gridPnts.rows(), 2);
259 output = gridPnts * trans;
```

The point of compiling with `-mfma` was to see if I could improve performance.  Is this a bug in `Eigen` or more likely did I use it incorrectly?

Comment: [This](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/549772) *may* be relevant. On a unrelated note; be careful with `-ffast-math` - make sure you know what tricks it pulls and where you can get wrong results due to it - it's useful *if* you know what you are doing, but be aware that it's breaking the standard and there are tricky pitfalls - my personal experience is that the limited performance gain is not worth the hours spent tracking down weird bugs..

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the comments on `-ffast-math`.  The exercise here was to see what performance gains/loses could be found just with compiler options.  If we decide to use it we will certainly need to thoroughly review it as you suggest.

Comment: You are welcome. For safe performance gains using compiler options I'd suggest you benchmark `-O2` vs `-O3` vs `-Os` and you most definitely want to investigate LTO and PGO - the last two has *in my case* lead to significant reductions in executable/library sizes as well as measurable speedups, and all without having to pull tricks that break guarantees provided by the standard (you do get longer build times with LTO though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To debug illegal instruction you should first of all look at the disassembly, not backtrace or source code. In your case though, even from the source code you can easily see that the offending (*illegal*) instruction is [`vfmadd231pd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VFMADD132PD:VFMADD213PD:VFMADD231PD.html), which is from the FMA instruction set extension. But SandyBridge CPUs, one of which you have, don't support this ISA extension, so by enabling it in the compiler you have shot yourself in the foot.

On Linux you can check whether your CPU supports FMA by this shell command:

```
grep -q '\<fma\>' /proc/cpuinfo && echo supported || echo not supported
```

Answer (score 6):

`-mfma` adds the [FMA instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) to the set of allowed instructions. You need at least an Intel-Haswell or AMD-Piledriver CPU for that.

Adding `-m`*InstructionSet* additionally to `-march=native` will never help -- either it was included already or it will allow the compiler to use illegal instructions (on your CPU).

Comment: If his goal is to improve performance on his machine, replacing `-march=native` with `-mtune=native` is counter-productive.